# Computer Control Panel Questions

Tags: architecture

I am not asking for the answer to the question. I am looking for how can I find these answers on my computer? I went to control panel and found most of these but I do not want to confuse anything.

1) What company manufactured the computer you are using? **Hewlett Packard**
2)How many bytes are in its main memory? **8GB**
3)How many registers are in its CPU?
4)How many bits are in each register? **64**
5)How many bits are in a single instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you answered three of those, I assume you *found* the "System" icon the the control panel.

In there you should also be able to see the processor type, such as `E6850`, and then go looking for the data sheets for that CPU on the net. That will tell you how many registers there are.

The number of bits in a single instruction depends on the instruction itself. If it's a CISC processor (as most Windows CPUs present themselves as), that will almost certainly be variable.